# How can I control my images and create an animation with it in my listview?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working with a listview where I gather images. I do it succesfully but I now wish to add an animation to it. I start off by having the images completely 0 in terms of opacity and then I wish to increase it with a `.FadeTo(1, 1000, Easing.SinIn);` once the images has been gathered.

As I am working with a listview I cannot use x:name so I am not sure how to solve it with a listview.

This is my current code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listview" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <AbsoluteLayout>

                          <Image Source = "{Binding image}" Opacity = "{Binding animation}"/>

                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Code page:

```
public class info
{
   public string image {get; set;}
   public int animation {get;set;}
}

List<info> myList = new List<info>();

    async void loadCategories()
    {

        var getInfo = await databaseCS.gettheinfo();

        listview.ItemsSource = null;
        myList = new List<info>();

        foreach (var theitems in getInfo["results"])
        {
           myList.add (new info()
           {
              image = theitems["image"].ToString(),
              animation = 0
           });
        }

      //how can I now create a FadeTo function to make the images return to 1 again once it has been gathered?
      listview.ItemsSource = myList;
     }
```

UPDATED CODE when I use the CustomImage code provided by the answer below!

The bool:

```
public class info : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _result;

    public string image {get; set;}

    public bool isImageShowing
    {
        get {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GET");
                return _result;
            }

        set {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SET");
                _result = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsImageShowing");
        }
    }
}
```

When i add the image to the list:

```
myList.add (new info()
{
       image = theitems["image"].ToString(),
       isImageShowing = true
});
```

Code runs and the images appear, but i see no animation. In the log i get "SET" 3 times as I gather 3 images. The last part to complete this is to connect the `public string image {get; set;}`/my `<Image>` in xaml to the `CustomImage`if I am not mistaken but I am not quite sure on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to perform the animation on your `Image`, I would say define your animation on an extension of the `Image` class.

I would also suggest that you create a bindable property on the extension to toggle the visibility through your animation.

something like below

```
public class CustomImage : Image
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsImageShowingProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsImageShowing", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomImage), false, BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnImageShowingChanged);

    private static void OnImageShowingChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if(newValue == null) return;

        var img = (CustomImage)bindable;
        var b = (bool)newValue;

        if(b)
        {
            img.ShowImage();
        }
        else
        {
            img.HideImage();
        }
    }

    public bool IsImageShowing
    {
        get {  return (bool)GetValue(IsImageShowingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsImageShowingProperty, value); }
    }

    public void ShowImage()
    {
        this.FadeTo(1, 1000, Easing.SinIn);
    }

    public void HideImage()
    {
        this.FadeTo(0, easing: Easing.SinIn);
    }
}
```

Now in your `Info` class, instead of having the `Animation` integer property, create a bool property to toggle the image animation and bind it to the `IsImageShowingProperty`. Once you have added the data to your `ListView.ItemsSource`, go through and toggle the boolean property on each item and it should run the animation.

Also make sure to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `Info` class.

**UPDATE:** 
if you need to run the animation when the data loads add this to your `CustomImage` class

```
protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
{
    base.OnBindingContextChanged();
    if(IsImageShowing)
    {
        this.ShowImage();
    }
}
```

Also make sure to set the image Opacity to 0 when your initialize your CustomImage, otherwise you wouldn't see the fade in effect

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! Will check it out right away and test it

Comment: Getting closer to solving this. Will update post in a few minutes to show my progress.

Comment: I updated the post now with my attempt to solve this with your CustomImage code

Comment: How do I connect the string image to the CustomImage/the <Image> I have in xaml?

Comment: I think its all working but as you can see in the `CustomImage` class the animation occurs when the `IsImageShowing` property changes. So if you initially set the `isImageShowing` property on your info class to false. and then go through and toggle to true, you will see the animation run.

Comment: alternatively if you want the images to run the animation when first loaded. then running the Animation from `OnBindingContextChanged` of the `CustomImage` class should work

Comment: would be very awesome if you could show an example with code!! would appreciate it a lot. because with my current code it seems like it is not working